# Check for file's existence using partial filename in windows

Tags: batch-file

I am new to windows batch script.
In windows batch script, i want to search for the existence of file.
**file name will be abcd_date_time_with_sec.**

I am able to come up with the code with **abcd_date_time(withoutsec).**

So, i want to search for a file abcd_date_time*. That is i want to search for a file with date and time(hours and min without second)

Please help.

Comment: `for %%I in (abcd_date_time*) do set "file=%%~I"`.  See `help for` in a cmd console for more info.

Answer (score 1):

A wildcard might return multiple results, a `for` will return them in alphabetical order on ntfs drives / otherwise the order is undetermined.
So the question is:

- do you want to know of the existence of at least one occurence,
- the number of matches
- or return a special one (newest/oldest)

The following batch will

- use dir with /ON (order by name)
- pipe to findstr to number the finds
- store finds in a pseudo array `File[#]`
- echo status and the array if filled with entries

---

```
@Echo off
Set "Search=abcd_*_*"
Set cnt=0
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in (
  'dir /B /ON /A-D "%Search%" ^|Findstr /i /n "^" '
) do set "File[%%A]=%%~B"&Set Cnt=%%A
Echo Search "%Search%" got %Cnt% result(s)
For /L %%C in (1,1,%Cnt%) Do Set File[%%C]
Pause
```

To order ascending by Creation date use `dir /b /OD /TC`,  descending `dir /B /O-D /TC`

Comment: When I run a jar file it ll create an output file as name_date_timewithsec. I need to write A batch script which checks whether the output file is created or not. So I ll need to search like output_date_time without seconds...since seconds change I can't use it..

Comment: From your question it's unclear if `_date_time` is meant literal or a placeholder, please provide some more real world examples in your edited question. You should read what a [mcve] is.

Comment: Apologies for the unclear explanation.  I have jar file and if i run it, an output file will be produced with this name as output_date_time.  ie., if today's date is 22/5/2017.. time is 11.20:30 seconds the output file name will be output_2552017_112030.  I need to write a batch script to check whether output is generated or not.  Since the file generated by the jar file has included seconds as well , i wanted to know whether this is possible or not: output_2252017_1120* ie to check whether output file got generated with the date and time without seconds.  Please help